# Unit Tests fail to run in XCode/Xctool

Tags: ios, continuous-integration, xcode7, xcodebuild, xctool

When I run my tests using Xcodebuild or Xctool, I see that the tool builds and installs the app into the simulator but fails to run the test. It is stuck forever in either `Touching <app-name>.xctest` when I use *xcodebuild* or `Launching and Running tests` when using *xctool*. I can see that the simulator is launched with its default homescreen but does not progress after that. This happens as part of a continuous integration environment I am trying to setup.

I do a `clean test` when using either tool. I also run `xcrun simctl shutdown "iPhone 6" || true` and `killall "Simulator" || true` before running the xcode commands to ensure the simulator is turned off. I also tried pre-launching the simulator and waiting before initiating the test command since I read somewhere that it could help. Please note that this issue does not happen always. It happens like around 3 out of 10 times but at times, it gets even more frequent. There is no logs/trails that I could work on to debug this issue. Any help/leads would be great!

**Xcode Version**: 7.0.1 
**Xctool Version**: 0.2.7 
**Simulator**: IPhone 6 
**OS**: Yosemite (10.10.5)

Thanks

Comment: I can see that this [Xctool Issue](https://github.com/facebook/xctool/issues/170) works with the same issue but my xctool is well updated to have all those fixes and I am still running into the same issue.